# DB Trigger for Sending an email not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a custom database sql Trigger which inserts a new row if the previous condition has been satisfied.

The problem is, the confirmed_Erp flag on the database does not get actioned if I include the email section of the code below which I have commented out.

Do I need to add a delay or how could I rewrite this to ensure that the confirmed_Erp flag is set to 1 and therefore the email will send. one of the email conditions is confirmed_erp = 1

There is an app which is running on top of the database which runs jobs and once a job completed the confirmed_erp flag in the database changes to 1.

Code:

```
      begin
      select @new_id = max(id) from jobr_generic;
      insert jobr_generic (id, type, jobr_ts, customerno, str_attr1,str_attr3, 
      dec_attr1, str_attr4,str_attr5, str_attr6, 


str_attr7,str_attr8,str_attr9,str_attr10,str_attr11,str_attr12,str_attr13,str_attr14,str_attr15,str_attr16,str_attr17,str_attr18,str_attr19,str_attr20, send_erp,species, maincut, subcut, meatgroup, packtype, factorycode, supplyingsite, currency)
       values (@new_id+1,  '235', getdate(),  @customerno,@attr1,   @attr3, @decattr1, @attr4,    @attr5,    @attr6,    @attr7,   @attr8,   @attr9,   @attr10,   @attr11,   @attr12,   @attr13,   @attr14,   @attr15,   @attr16,   @attr17,   @attr18,   @attr19,   @attr20,   1,       @species,@maincut,@subcut,@meatgroup,@packtype,@factorycode,@supplyingsite,@currency);
       end 
       if @type ='235' AND @CONFIRMED_ERP = 1 AND @itemrequestfor = 'P'
        begin
        declare @body2 varchar(1024)
        set @body2 = 'Primal Item: '+@attr16+ ' has been created and is ready 

          for use.'
          exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'DoNotReplyMailProfile',
            @recipients= 'test@test.com',
            @copy_recipients= 'test1@test.com',
            @subject = 'A Primal Item has been Created',
            @body = @body2,
            @body_format = 'TEXT',
            @exclude_query_output = 1 ;

            end
```

Comment: If you want help, post all the code of your trigger - not a snippet and not something that includes commented-out code that may or may not be relevant to the problem. It appears that you may suffer from the a very common mistake - assuming a single row is affected. I suggest you go review past discussions to understand how to correct that one first. While doing that you can consider what should happen when multiple rows exist in your trigger logic.

Comment: To capture the rows that were just changed, use the `inserted` table. However it's a _bad_ idea to send an email from a trigger. If anything fails, the trigger fails and the data change is rolled back

Comment: Hi,I have just removed the comments from my code.

Comment: The entire code is around 300 lines thus why I did not post the whole thing here.

Comment: Does your code use the `inserted` table?